# index.js depends on 'localforage'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, commonjs, localforage, ionic-storage

I got this warning, but I dont understand why 'localforage' depends on CommonJS. I had googled for few days, but I can't find any solution that fit with my problems.

```
  WARNING
    C:\xxx\node_modules\@ionic\storage\dist\esm\index.js depends on 'localforage'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
    For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies
```

I use ionic storage to store data, and it directly stores in "_ionicstorage > _ionickv". I don't use localforage in any of my pages inside ionic. How to resolve this issue? Should i replace the whole code that uses ionic storage to different storage?

**Note:** I don't want to add allowed dependencies in angular.json file since it is not fully solved the problem (because that only allow commonJS module instead of resolve the issue).